# Why does the prediction of my model change between scaled and unscaled data when using standard scaler?

Tags: python

When I tried to scale my data using the standard scaler, the model gives an incorrect prediction:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 
st=StandardScaler()
x_train=st.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test=st.transform(x_test)

arry = [51,1,0,140,261,0,186,1,0,2,0,2]
tes = np.asarray(arry)
se = tes.reshape(1,-1)
svc_load.predict(se)
```

OUTPUT:  array([0], dtype=int64)

but with the same inputs but without scaling the data:

```
    arry = [51,1,0,140,261,0,186,1,0,2,0,2]
    tes = np.asarray(arry)
    se = tes.reshape(1,-1)
    svc_load.predict(se)
```

OUTPUT: array([1], dtype=int64)
which is correct.
I'm new in machine learning. Can anyone help me with this?

I'm using the GaussianNB classifier.

Comment: How was the model trained? Where features scaled? What is `predict_proba(se)` for both.  As it is, you cannot know if whether the true answer was pure lucky guess.

Answer (score 0):

**Rule:** If you trained the model with scaled data, test with scaled data. If not, test with raw data. Using [pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html)'s `fit` and `predict` makes this easier.

By the way, Gaussian Naive Bayes model which you used does not require normalization since features are only compared to each other.